# App crashes AsyncTask downloading JSON from remote server

Tags: android, json, okhttp

I am working on an Android app and downloading a JSON string from remote server.
This is my function:

```
private void getAddressesFromDB() {

    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    calendarios.clear();

   this is line 218->  AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... addressesIds) {


            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();


            Request request = new Request.Builder().addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
                    .url("https://...cargar_calendario.php?colegio="+colegio)
                    .build();

            try {
                okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                Log.d("HOLA ADDRESSES", "ESTOY EN START:CREATE colegio=>"+response.body().string() );

                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());<- this is line 237



                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    Calendario calendario = new Calendario(object.getString("holidayDescr"),object.getString("dt"), object.getString("lectivo"));


                }


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {


            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    };

    asyncTask.execute();
}
```

This is the received JSON string:

```
[{"dt":"2018-01-01","holidayDescr":"Lectivo","lectivo":"1"},{"dt":"2018-01-02","holidayDescr":"Lectivo","lectivo":"1"},{"dt":"2018-01-03","holidayDescr":"Lectivo","lectivo":"1"},{"dt":"2018-01-04","holidayDescr":"Lectivo","lectivo":"1"},{"dt":"2018-01-05","holidayDescr":"Lectivo","lectivo":"1"},{"dt":"2018-01-06","holidayDescr":"","lectivo":"0"},{"dt":"2018-01-07","holidayDescr":"","lectivo":"0"},{"dt":"2018-01-08","holidayDescr":"Lectivo","lectivo":"1"},{"dt":"2018-01-09","holidayDescr":"Lectivo","lectivo":"1"},{"dt":"2018-01-10","holidayDescr":"Lectivo","lectivo":"1"}]
```

And this is the exception message:

```
    --------- beginning of crash
2018-11-01 03:31:21.028 32425-592/com.juarezserver.pupilam E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.juarezserver.pupilam, PID: 32425
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.rangeEquals(RealBufferedSource.java:408)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.rangeEquals(RealBufferedSource.java:402)
        at okhttp3.internal.Util.bomAwareCharset(Util.java:432)
        at okhttp3.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:174)
        at com.juarezserver.pupilam.fragment.CalendarioFragment$1.doInBackground(CalendarioFragment.java:237)
        at com.juarezserver.pupilam.fragment.CalendarioFragment$1.doInBackground(CalendarioFragment.java:218)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Are you sure those lines you marked in the code are correct? You might make sure your build and stack trace are both current. The stack trace seems to indicate that the Exception is happening at one of the `response.body().string()` calls; I would say the second. The Exception message, I'm guessing, is saying that you can only call `string()` once, possibly? Store the result from the first call, and use that in both places, instead of `response.body().string()` twice.

Comment: @MikeM., the marked lines are correct.

Comment: Please try my suggestion anyway.

Comment: Yeah, there ya go. Line 237 is the second `response.body().string()` call.

Comment: @MikeM., sorry, line 237 is another code line, already changed in my question

Comment: @MikeM., I have removed .string() from that line, and the app doesn't crash anymore, there is a warning now:  org.json.JSONException: Not a primitive array: class okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody

Comment: I would guess because the received JSON is an array of objects, not just an array of simple values.

Comment: @MikeM., and the for... clausel is not even launched

Comment: Well, you'll have to do some debugging. Did you remove all of `response.body().string()`, or just `string()`? If the latter, are you sure calling `body()` twice isn't causing an issue, too? Also, have you double-checked the value of `response.body().string()` there? What about `array.length()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
   try {
                okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                Log.d("HOLA ADDRESSES", "ESTOY EN START:CREATE colegio=>"+response.body().string() );

                client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                 }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
        } else {
                  JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);<- this is line 237



                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    Calendario calendario = new Calendario(object.getString("holidayDescr"),object.getString("dt"), object.getString("lectivo"));


                }
        }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your log statement close RealBufferedSource at the end of string method and you can change the log statement something like this.

```
Log.d("HOLA ADDRESSES", "ESTOY EN START:CREATE colegio=>"+response.body());
```

Ideal solution would be create model class for your response data and make change to return array of data  from the api call.